# Error: ENFILE: file table overflow, scandir while run reaction on Mac

Tags: node.js, reactjs, meteor, npm

I'm trying to install and run Reaction on mac osx 10.12.15 within below command

npm install -g reaction-cli
reaction init
cd reaction
reaction

Then I got below error I'm just fresh with Reactjs developer so it is simply nervously. And it simply compatible with the package version but how can i solve this problem

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
/Users/sopheak/.meteor/packages/templating-compiler/.1.3.2.1411czp++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileTemplatesBatch.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:190
      throw error;
      ^
Error: ENFILE: file table overflow, scandir '/Users/sopheak/Documents/cam/react/reaction/packages/gridfs'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:808:18)
    at Object.wrapper (/tools/fs/files.js:1586:35)
    at readDirectory (/Users/sopheak/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.0.15auley++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fs/watch.js:338:26)
    at Watcher._fireIfDirectoryChanged (/Users/sopheak/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.0.15auley++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fs/watch.js:490:23)
    at /Users/sopheak/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.0.15auley++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fs/watch.js:747:12
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/sopheak/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.0.15auley++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at Watcher._checkDirectories (/Users/sopheak/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.0.15auley++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fs/watch.js:736:7)
    at new Watcher (/Users/sopheak/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.5.0.15auley++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fs/watch.js:435:10)
    at setupClientWatcher (/tools/runners/run-app.js:800:23)
    at [object Object]._.extend._runOnce (/tools/runners/run-app.js:811:7)
    at [object Object]._.extend._fiber (/tools/runners/run-app.js:890:28)
    at /tools/runners/run-app.js:417:12
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

This is might be due to the limit on file open files on mac. By default it is set to low. You will need to increase the default size.

```
$ echo kern.maxfiles=65536 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
$ echo kern.maxfilesperproc=65536 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
$ sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=65536
$ sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=65536
$ ulimit -n 65536
```

Refer this [link](http://blog.mact.me/2014/10/22/yosemite-upgrade-changes-open-file-limit) for more details.

Comment: its happening in windows 10... do you know what the command for windows?

Comment: Having same ulimit on `kern.maxfiles` and `kern.maxfilesperproc` got me random crashes of different programs while trying to build stuff (because node depleted all the limit and other programs couldn't open files). Also, 65k is a bit of small limit considering current size of node_modules =)

Comment: Thanks! You are the best! I had this issue when trying to publish thru expo

Comment: This worked for me, but with increasing to `524288`

Answer (score 3):

I was facing similar issue.
I tried with maxfiles=65536 but got the same error.

Then I tried with 524288, as suggested by one in comments and it worked.

**Command:**

```
echo kern.maxfiles=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
echo kern.maxfilesperproc=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=524288
sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=524288
ulimit -n 524288
```

Hope it will help others too

Answer (score 1):

sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 16384 16384 && ulimit -n 16384